# add Google Conversion Tracking code after submission or click

Tags: jquery, iframe, google-ads-api

Stock adding google coversion tracking code after ajax successful.
I can't put the code just as is in a div and set the display to none and then change the css display value because the code will be tracked from google so i have to inject it after ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was originally from [Ollo](http://ollomedia.com/how-to-track-adwords-conversions-on-click-with-jquery/), this adds 1x1 iframe inside a div after submission.
What i did was to create

`<div id="converter"></div>`

and then add this simple jQuery

`$("#converter").html("<iframe height='1' width='1' name='converter' src='tracking.html'></iframe>");`

after ajax successful.
Then create **tracking.html** which contains the Google conversion code.